# how implicit keyword works in scala?

Tags: scala

I'm new in Scala but familiar with Java.

Please check this two methods

```scala
def jsonPar(name:String): ScallaopOption[Map[String, Map[String, String]]] : opt[Map[String, Map[String, String]]](name,required = true)(jsonMapper)
    
def jsonMapper : ValueConverter[Map[String, Map[String, String]]] = 
    scallop.singleArgConverter(json)
```

now there is `opt` method in `ScallopConfBase` class

```scala
def opt[A](name : scala.Predef.String, short : scala.Char, and so on upto 10 more params)(implicit conv : org.rogach.scallop.ValueConverter[A]) : org.rogach.scallop.ScallopopOption[A]
```

I'm stuck this code to understand, here are my concerns

1. opt needs to have 10 input params to execute, but in `def jsonPar`, only `(name,required = true)` is passed to opt, how ?
2. what's a importance of adding  `(implicit conv : org.rogach.scallop.ValueConverter[A]) : org.rogach.scallop.ScallopopOption[A]` in `opt` method ?
3. what `ScallaopOption[Map[String, Map[String, String]]] : opt[Map[String, Map[String, String]]](name,required = true)(jsonMapper)` part is doing ?

can anyone share ? I'm trying to thing from java perspective, but still not able to understand.

Comment: Usually it is better to [ask one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735).

Comment: @Pshemo, these are linked to my doubt

Comment: even if you are trying to think from the Java perspective, I doubt this is related to Java... as the [tag:java] tag states: "*... Use this tag when you're having problems using or understanding the language itself. ...*" (meant is the Java Programming Language)

Comment: @Levi Ramsey, can you please share something ?

Comment: As mentioned, I voted to close because there are multiple questions and edited the tags because this doesn't really have anything to do with java.  At least one of the questions you're asking can only really be answered with posting (e.g. a github link) the full definition of `opt`.

Answer (score 2):

Broadly, what `implicit` does is provide hints to the compiler to use when normal compilation fails.

For example, `implicit` conversions (which shouldn't generally be used) and `implicit` classes come into play when you try to call a method on an object whose type doesn't include that method.  In that scenario, the compiler will, rather than reject the code immediately, search for an implicit conversion to a type which has that method and include a call to that conversion so that the method can be called.  `implicit` classes work similarly (and use basically the same mechanism under the hood) as implicit conversions: if there's an implicit class available which can take that object as a constructor parameter, the compiler will effectively insert a `new ImplicitClassName(originalObject).methodThatDoesntExistOnOriginalObject(...)`.

`implicit` parameters meanwhile rely on the idea of an `implicit` scope.  If there's no explicitly provided argument for the implicit parameter, then the compiler will use an argument of that type from the implicit scope of the caller.  Inside the method taking the `implicit` parameter, those parameters become part of the implicit scope so that that method can make calls using implicits.

The `: ScallopOption[Map[String, Map[String, String]]]` just means that the method returns a `ScallopOption[Map[String, Map[String, String]]]`.  `: ScallaopOption[Map[String, Map[String, String]]] : opt` is not valid Scala; I suspect that the second `:` is an `=`.

You haven't provided the definition of `opt`, but it looks like it uses default parameters, so explicit parameters can be omitted in favor of the default values.

Comment: Note that because `implicit` is used for so many different things, Scala 3 removes the keyword and provides the different functionalities through different keywords.

Comment: @LevisRamsey, opt is present in abstract class > ScallopConfBase.class, secondly can you please share why (name,required = true)  used as opt's parameters, becasue if see the opt def it can have aprox 10 input params, then from where these two are being used and why ?